# How to filter on index while creating a Matplotlib graph?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I’m trying to create a matplotlib graph by filtering the index column, which in my data frame is a date time column.

Here are the steps I follow to create the unfiltered graph.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5], index = [‘01/01/2021’,’01/02/2021’,’01/03/2021’,’01/04/2021’,’01/05/2021’], columns = [‘quantity’])

fig, axes = plt.subplots()
axes.scatter(data = df, x = df.index, y = ‘quantity’)
```

This work as expected. In order to avoid creating a data frame containing filtered data, I was trying to create the filtered graph in one line, basically doing something like this.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplot()
axes.scatter(data = df[df.index < ‘01/04/2021’], x = df.index, y = ‘quantity’)
```

This obviously doesn’t work because x and y are not the same size.

One workaround is to create a new column in the df, which is an exact copy of the index, but I was wondering if there was an easier and cleaner solution that is escaping my mind.

Answer (score 0):

you are absoluted right. There are two ways:

1. Filtering the x-Values similar to the data:

```py
fig, axes = plt.subplot()
axes.scatter(data = df[df.index < '01/04/2021'], x = df[df.index < '01/04/2021'].index, y = 'quantity')
```

2. restraining one axis of the plot:

```py
fig, axes = plt.subplot()
axes.scatter(data = df, x = df.index, y = 'quantity')
axes.xlim(df[df.index < '01/04/2021'].index)
```